# How can i use field inside method?

Tags: java

to begin with, this is my first question in here.

I want to use double *mebleg* inside *transfer* method, and I has equaled *mebleg* to *balance* in constructor, but unfortunately, the amount of parameter of balance doesn't go with mebleg into **transfer** method. how can I solve this problem?

I am new at programming. that's why if my question was answered, could you suggest that links of answers?

```
class Acount {

    static double mebleg;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Acount a = new Acount(100);
        Acount b = new Acount(0.0);
        Acount c = new Acount(0.0);
        Acount.transfer(a, b, 50);
        Acount.transfer(b, c, 25);

    }

    public Acount(double balance) {
        mebleg = balance;
    }

    public static void transfer(Acount from, Acount to, double howMuch) {
        System.out.println(Acount.mebleg - howMuch);

    }

}
```

Comment: You probably don't want to use a static variable (`mebleg`) for balance. It would be the same for all accounts.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error? The wrong output?

Comment: @ModusTollens please, look at carefully my codes, I have use keyword "static". and **mebleg** should be static for all of accounts because of amount of money (I mean 100.0, 0.0)

Comment: @Mureinik output is 
**-50.0**
**-25.0** but I don't  know why output is negative, why should not it be positive ?

Comment: @nihat I _did_ look carefully at your code. I have been looking carefully at code for 20 years. Believe me: the balance should not be static.

Comment: @ModusTollens, okay, I am trying to remove this static keyword but the next **Acount.transfer(b,c,25);** is still  negative in output

Comment: @nihat your sample code does nowhere alter your account balance. If it becomesnegative you did not show us your full code. Anyway, see my answer below it shows a possible implementation which does have one balance per account (i.e. non-static) and a working transfer method.

Answer (score 3):

You should not make the field static if you want to use it for instances. If you change that, your `transfer()` method should use `from.mebleg` (or a associated getter).

```
double mebleg;

public Account(double initialBalance) { mebleg = initialBalance; }

public static void transfer(Acount from, Acount to, double howMuch)
{
    from.mebleg -= howMuch;
    to.mebleg += howMuch;
}
```

(Not discussing various existing issues like transactions, concurrency, error handling and usage of double for monetary units here).